# Error in Manifest merging

Tags: android, manifest

I am trying to draw Driving distance and travel time duration between two locations in Google Map Android API V2.
I am working in the Android Studio 1.4 environment
I have used a blank activity,and 
In my build.gradle(module) I have the following code

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sathyaprakash.locationdistancetimemapv2"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
dependencies 
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0'
}
```

But i am getting a single error 
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors,see log.

Please help me..
Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your manifest file

Comment: @sathya can you please post you error log cat?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove this line from the `Manifest file`

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I hope so it will work.